# Codeigniter -> Simple select all query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my my model:

```
$this->db->select('companyName,companySlogan,companyContact,companyEmail,companyWebsite,companyPhone,companyFax,companyAddress');
$result = $this->db->get('companyDetails');
```

How would I return my `$result` so that I can call it via my controller in the following form?

```
$data['companyName'] = $this->quote->companyDetails->companyName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably create a function `getCompanyDetails($companyName)` in model. Then call this method from your controller. `$this->quote->getCompanyDetails('abc');`

Something like below. Note, please test this and do minor changes if there is an error. The basic idea is given below.

```
public function getCompanydetails($companyName)
{ 
$this->db->select('companyName,companySlogan,companyContact,companyEmail,companyWebsite,companyPhone,companyFax,companyAddress');
    $result = $this->db->get($companyName);
    return result->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Would I have to create a $field for every item?

Comment: if you want to select every fields from the table, you can just use `$this->db->get($companyName);` no need that select method call.

Comment: ahh I get you now I think $companyName could be $value and still work